# Java slider with dial look and feel

Tags: java, swing, jslider

I trying to create a JSlider object which has its line looking like an arc, there are minimum number of tick marks (though some may not have a value) and the slider indicator is a simple line drawn from the centre of the arc to the currently selected tick mark. It looks like I may have to extend the BasicSliderUI and override the various paint methods. Is there an example of something like this already or do I have create this object from scratch?

Comment: Making a straight line drag across or up/down a GUI using a mouse is a natural movement.  But 'radial movement' is a lot less natural, and harder to do.   For the sake of your users, please drop this idea.

Comment: You might also look at [tag:jfreechart] dial plots, mentioned [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6799536/230513).

Comment: Unfortunately I have to mimic an existing user interface and for some reason the original designer chose these dials. I agree it is a bad UI but that is what I am stuck with. Although since this is a touch screen interface the line may not be as big a problem as you think.

Answer (score 2):

This [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6996263/230513) illustrates how to override the `paintTrack()` method of `BasicSliderUI`. It looks like you could draw an [`Arc2D`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/geom/Arc2D.html) to get the effect you want.

Comment: More on rendering `Arc2D` may be found [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7343420/230513).

Comment: The only problem with using a slider is that it looks like the labels are always drawn below the track. I actually need to draw them above the line. For the amount of overrideing it may be easier to just have my own component. It just that I need the behaviour of setSnapToTicks(true). That why I wanted to start from the slider. I had already found the gradient paint example and that is what I have been using in my prototype.